# Problem regarding inApp purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Hi i want to add test inAppPurchase in my iphone app.I have seen various tutorials and tried to implement it but i am getting all products in invalid  product identifier .Following are the steps i have taken to add inAppPurchase:

1) I have created a new appID without wildcard characters and enabled inAppPurchase.

2)I have created a distribution provisioning profile based on that app ID.

3) Created an app on itunes connect with same name as of my app.

4) Created one inAppPurchase product with a unique id  and cleared it for sale .

5)I have used tier 1 for it .

6)I have completed ios free applications contract but i have not filled ios paid applications form

7)I have tried both "upload binary and rejecting it" and "without uploading any binary"

My code is

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{



   NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.my uniques product id" ];
   productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
   productsRequest.delegate = self;
   [productsRequest start];


}


- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
   NSArray *products = response.products;



   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"started" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[response.invalidProductIdentifiers count]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   [alert release];


   }
```

here i am getting my product id as invalid .I do not know what could be wrong with my approach or code.Please tell me the correct way to test inAppPurchase in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete IOS paid applications contract. Also provide tax & banking information.These need to be completed to Test In-App-Purchase.

Comment: Can you give me your skype id.?
I need some help

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 24 hours for a product you've uploaded to propagate to all of Apple's servers. Until it does you'll get an invalid product message for your call. Depending on how long it has been since you created the product, it may just be a matter of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

this link contains All steps you need to follow before use InAPP purchase https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html